# Implement inputRef prop with Material UI TextField custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to hook up Material UI `TextField` with an input component of my own. The code utilizing the `TextField` looks like this:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="inputData"
  options={inputData}
  getOptionLabel={option => option.text}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="inputData"
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent: () => <Input name="inputData" />
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

and the `Input` component code is simple:

`const Input = () => <input />`

It will become more complicated but for now I'd like to get this simple code to work. The error I get is that `inputRef.current is null` which is probably caused by the lack of `InputElement` interface implementation in the `Input` component. Please see the Material UI [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) below the code snippet for the info on `InputElement` interface. In other words my `Input` component doesn't handle the `inputRef` prop Material UI needs.

How do I properly integrate a custom `Input` component with Material UI `TextField` ?

Here's a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-bash-pxqq0.

Comment: This is exactly the same question you already asked... [Custom input component with Material UI Autocomplete TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267635/custom-input-component-with-material-ui-autocomplete-textfield)

Comment: Oh sorry for that. Deleted the old one.

Comment: This is not the right approach. If you already have a question that didn't get enough attention and you want more people to look at it - set a Bounty on said question. Do not just open a new question every other day. What if this question will not get an answer within the next 24hr? You will open again a new question?